# Anyone know of a plugin to show Category count?

Tags: categories, conditionals, count

Basically want to find the number of entries per category in order to perform a conditional to show different content based on the entry count. Essentially:

if count  = 2 then this
if count is less than 2 then something else.

Native way would be preferred  but any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think GWcode Categories would be the easiest way to do this: http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories. It can also do a great number of other things with categories.

There's also an add-on just for counting category entries: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/category-count

I actually use both on my site. I don't think there is a native way to do this without an add-on.

Comment: Great! Category Count looks exactly the job!