# How many entries for a given category?

Tags: categories, category-group

Given a category (not the category group), is there a way to get the count entries assigned to that category? I'm hoping for a native EE solution. This seems to suggest that there isn't one: [Anyone know of a plugin to show Category count?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/19377/anyone-know-of-a-plugin-to-show-category-count). Can I do this in EE only?

Comment: If you have received the answer to your question please choose your desired answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a plugin that will give you the desired result you need without a custom query.

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/entries-number

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest and quickest solution if no one wrote a plug-in already would be:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT COUNT(entry_id) AS cat_count FROM exp_category_posts WHERE cat_id=1"}{cat_count}{/exp:query}
```

Note: Untested.

Obviously replace the cat_id value with the category ID you want to count entries for. :)

If you don't have the category ID in the URL, but have its category_url_title:

```
SELECT COUNT(entry_id) AS cat_count
FROM exp_category_posts AS cp
JOIN exp_categories AS c ON cp.cat_id = c.cat_id
WHERE c.cat_url_title = "{segment_X}"
```